# Swift: Missing Argument Error

Tags: swift, swift2

Im having an issue here when trying to follow the first stanford lecture. I am assuming it is because I am using swift 2.... which was just recently released. (And the class is not) Below I show where I am getting errors. In the class the "enter" button on the calculator has the code `@IBAction func enter() {`  but in mine it is `@IBAction func enter(sender: UIButton) {`

Is this something I did wrong when bringing the button into my code? Any ways to fix? Let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet var display: UILabel!

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber: Bool = false

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
        }
    }

    @IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
        let operation = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
            enter() // Here is my error: *Missing Argument for parameter on the line of code that says enter()
        }
        switch operation {
            case "x":
                if operandStack.count >= 2 {
                    displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() * operandStack.removeLast()
                    enter() // Here is my error:  Again... 
                }

            default: break
        }
    }

    var operandStack = Array<Double>()



    @IBAction func enter(sender: UIButton) {
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        operandStack.append(displayValue)
        print("operandStack = \(operandStack)")
    }

    var displayValue: Double {
        get {
            return NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(display.text!)!.doubleValue
        }
        set {
            display.text = "\(newValue)"
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enter` requires an input parameter but you didn't supply it with any. Replace it with `enter(sender)`

```
@IBAction func operate(sender: UIButton) {
    let operation = sender.currentTitle!
    if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
        enter(sender)
    }

    switch operation {
        case "x":
            if operandStack.count >= 2 {
                displayValue = operandStack.removeLast() * operandStack.removeLast()
                enter(sender)
            }

        default: break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zoff, such an easy fix! You are the best. :D Ill accept the answer (says wait 5 min)

Comment: Don't worry youll get it :) Website is making me wait five min. You earned it.